# The background color of Div does not stretch to the end when media queries is used in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interface

The problem is quite simple and yet it's hard for me to get the solution.

This is the page that I have developed from the course.

[image: Site]

When I use *developer mode* and try to decrease the screen size. The background color of the div *(which has a classed named **".section-hero**)* does not stretch to the end.

[image]

Here is the code.

*The following one is the **HTML** section where*

[image: HTML code]

***.section-hero*** is the one that has the background color and it does not stretch to the end. And I want that stretched thing to happen in response to the changing screen size.

*This one is CSS*

[image: code]

[image: hero section]

And I have also include  on my header in HTML.

**It would be very nice of you if you could help me on this one.**

Comment: what do you mean by `when media queries`?

Comment: Please put your code direct into your question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for help with doing this.

Comment: When using media queries.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this under **.section-hero** in CSS

```
background-size: cover;
```

Reference : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this under `.section-hero` in CSS

```
background-size: cover;
```

Comment: It did not work.